# Excel sheet to python dict

Tags: python-3.x

Ive been looking around but cant find an easy solution to converting my sheet to a dictionary. My sheet look like this, where each string is placed in a row of its own and the columns ahead are empty. can i easily turn this into a dictionary or do i have to fill the empty cells with values?

Edit for clarity: the dashes are just there to represent the empty columns in front of the values. I have both a xls and csv file of the data. The dict should hold the first columns as keys, then the second and third as "subkeys(?)"and fourth row as values. The sheet look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt4Gm.jpg), and i I plan to use this in a QTreeView

```
key 1
----value 1
--------value a
--------value b
--------value c
----value 2
--------value d
--------value e
key 2
----value 3
--------value f
--------value g
--------value h
----value 4
--------value i
--------value j
```

Comment: Do you *actually* have an Excel file (like an `xls`/`xlsx` file) or just a CSV file?  Why is your file set up the way you describe?  Are the dashes part of your file?  What do you want the resulting `dict` to look like?

Comment: i tried to add some clarity to the question

Comment: does your `.xls` file contents look like this? http://i.imgur.com/CsjdE91.png

Comment: I does indeed, but everything is on a separate row. It looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/Jyx9p

Answer (score 1):

I'm embarrassed to post this very messy answer, but since it'll be the only answer here, I'll post it anyway. It was the only way I could figure out how to build that kind of nested dictionary from a spreadsheet.

Unfortunately, it's hardcoded - it would be much better to build it dynamically, if I can improve it later I'll update.

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("data.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
d = dict(dict())

c1 = [str(c.value) for c in sh.col(0) if c.value != '']
c2 = [str(c.value) for c in sh.col(1) if c.value != '']
c3 = [str(c.value) for c in sh.col(2) if c.value != '']

val1 = c2[0]
val2 = c2[1]
val3 = c2[2]
val4 = c2[3]

v1 = {val1: c3[0:3]}
v2 = {val2: c3[3:5]}
v3 = {val3: c3[5:8]}
v4 = {val4: c3[8:10]}

k1 = {c1[0]: [v1, v2]}
k2 = {c1[1]: [v3, v4]}

d.update(k1)
d.update(k2)
```

Then, printing the dictionary:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(d)
    {'key 1': [{'value 1': ['value a', 'value b', 'value c']},
               {'value 2': ['value d', 'value e']}],
     'key 2': [{'value 3': ['value f', 'value g', 'value h']},
               {'value 4': ['value i', 'value j']}]}
```

Until a better answer comes along, I hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: @Louvre did you still want to try to make the rows dynamic?